# Efficiency of multiple require-ing of modules in node.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

To simplify, let's have an `entry.js`, which requires `common.js` (with very universal functions), and `routines.js` (which contains project-specific functions). `routines.js` too requires `common.js`.

I don't expect the above scenario to be a problem, but in general, are the multiple requires, by modules which require one another a bad practice and is there a better approach? I'm thinking requiring within the `entry.js` and passing over to functions. Or is this microoptimizing and multiple requires are no big deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't imagine this being a big deal as [Node caches each "require" for you](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) as long as the resolved filename is exactly the same (in most instances it will be, however the [node docs list some cases where it may not be](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats))

I found [this post](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/) to have a nice simple explanation of how the module/require system in node works.